# Maven in Eclipse?

Tags: spring, eclipse, maven, spring-boot

I am a total beginner at maven, I have read about it online but I am still confused how it can be used. I have eclipse Oxygen version installed and when I open projects I can see maven project option is already there. I was even able to create a maven project using YouTube tutorial. But now then I saw popular plugin called m2eclipse but I am not able to comprehend why is it actually used; when my application ran without it.

I am learning maven to get started with spring boot but I am finding it really overwhelming where to begin with, and many of the tutorial sites state to download maven (But maven already comes along with eclipse?)

Please explain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Apache Maven](http://maven.apache.org/) is a build tool - a tool for compiling the source code of a project into a program that you can run (for example a jar file, or a war file that can be deployed on a Java EE application server). Besides automating all the tasks for building a project, it also gives you a standard way to organize your project and to keep track of dependencies (libraries that your project needs).

Why do you need such a tool?

When you write a small program that consists of one, or maybe a few source files, it's easy enough to compile it by hand on the command line, by directly using the Java compiler `javac` that comes with the JDK.

But when your project becomes more complex, and you have hundreds or even thousands of source files in multiple modules, it becomes really hard to keep track of everything and cumbersome to compile the files using `javac`. If your program needs libraries, it becomes even more complex, because you have to make sure that all the libraries are on the classpath, and some libraries need other libraries, which also have to be on the classpath.

A tool such as Maven helps you to compile all the source files in the right order and to keep track of all the libraries. Maven can automatically download libraries from the web and add them to your project, and downloading everything and building the whole project can be done with one simple command such as `mvn clean package`.

Spring Boot is part of the Spring Framework, which is a huge framework with tons of useful functionality for developing projects in Java. A Spring Boot project typically needs dozens of libraries, and it would be very hard to use if you'd have to keep track of all those libraries by hand - so that's why it uses Maven to manage all of this for you.

A Maven project is configured using a file named `pom.xml` - in that file, you describe your project and you put a list of libraries that your project needs. When you build your project, Maven will read the `pom.xml` file and figure out automatically what source files need to be compiled, and what libraries need to be downloaded.

Answer (score 2):

m2eclipse comes preinstalled in Eclipse (at least when selecting "Eclipse for Java developers" or "Eclipse for Java EE developer"), thats why you were able to use Maven by default.

Still you probably want a command line Maven, because that's most likely how it will eventually run on the CI server, sometimes Eclipse Maven installation can produce different result than the command line install.